# How to get Powerline colours working in Emacs Shell/Term mode?

Tags: shell, powerline, coloring

I have recently started using **Spacemacs** instead of VIM, because of great VHDL mode.

In vim (neovim) I used to use VIM as terminal emulator.
In Emacs I have encountered a bit of strange colour behaviour.
To be exact I don't mean different palette for "System colours",
that is not a problem.
Problem is missing colors in "Color cube" and completely discolored Powerline.

[image: bad colours]

While I would expect this (**KDE Konsole** or **neovim** terminal):

[image: correct colours]

Everything is set to **xterm-256**, so I don't know what is the problem. This occurs in both -nw (terminal) mode and GUI mode.

It seems that 256 color are somewhat degraded by emacs, see comparison of `colortest-256` command in **Emacs** and **Konsole** and also notice how **Powerline** is not coloured anymore.

Also note that colours in **Powerline** are wrong for both *background* and *letters*...

How can I fix this strange colour behaviour and get the shell **Powerline** (github.com/powerline/powerline) working under **Shell** or **Term** mode in Emacs?

Comment: Could you clarify the post a little to make your question explicit, please?

Comment: @Dan I have put a specific question in the end. Is it now better?

Comment: Thanks, yes.  It would also help if you could highlight what is different about the two screenshots.  When I looked closely, I saw that the system colors differed, but the thing that jumps out is that the color cubes look almost identical.

Comment: @Dan I have put the clarification. It is not System colours.. that is ok for me. Problem is that some colours are missing in Colour cube and also Powerline is completely without colors...

Comment: I think the Powerline colors are actually there, but maybe the font you're using is missing the glyphs that Powerline needs to make a solid box of color? You do have the funny branching arrow symbol, so maybe I'm wrong, but perhaps worth checking which font Emacs is using.

Comment: @Tyler I am using the exact same font in both Konsole and Emacs (Source Code Pro for Powerline).. In fact if I run Emacs with `-nw` option in terminal, it has the same effect on colours (and it must use the same font).

Comment: Ok, just a thought. I do notice a shift in colors between Emacs shell and xterm using the same settings. Don't know why :/

Comment: @Tyler I would not actually mind the colour shift. What I care most about is that Powerline colours are removed completely... If it had at least some colours, but not exactly those in Konsole I would accept that. The problem is that it seems to remove some colours also from that colour test and it seems that colours used in powerline are in this set of colours... I guess I'd have to play with colour theme of powerline..

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? For now I have set `POWERLEVEL9K_COLOR_SCHEME='light'` in my zshrc so that it was atleast ledgible